# Why referenced vector address cannot be dereferenced in cpp?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to dereference a referenced vector address as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> p;
    p.push_back(1);
    p.push_back(2);
    p.push_back(3);
    p.push_back(4);
    p.push_back(5);
    p.push_back(6);
    cout << (*(&p)) << endl;
    cout << (*(&p + 3)) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But it fails.

**Expecting output:**

```
1
4
```

Comment: `vector<int> p;` is a single vector.  You'd need `vector<int> p[4];` to do `cout << (*(&p + 3)) << endl;`

Comment: @Eljay oh, but I just wanted to do `p[0]` & `p[3]` in using pointers. Is it possible?

Comment: `*(&p[0])` and `*(&p[3])` ... but what you probably want is [`p.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

Comment: It looks as if you assume that `vector<int>` is just an array of ints. But it's a more complex data structure and the vector elements are stored on the heap.

Comment: @user3243499 `&(p[0])`

Comment: @Codo where the data of the vector is stored is controlled by the passed allocator and can be changed. But the important part is that the data vector stores, is not enclosed within the vector and as of that the location of the data is not related to the location of the vector itself.

Comment: `But it fails.` Describe the failure in more detail. Did you get wrong output? What output did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<int> p;` is an *object* that manages consecutive storage of elements of type `int`.

`&p` would be an address of such an object. What that object contains is unspecified. You can expect a `vector` object to contain, e.g. the pointer to an array of elements allocated on the heap, the current size and capacity.

To get a pointer to the underlying elements, use `p.data()`.

To access a specific element of a vector can use the overloaded `operator[]` (e.g. `p[0]`, `p[3]`).

An iterator (e.g. `p.begin()`) can also be used as an abstraction around a pointer to an element:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> p;
    p.push_back(1);
    p.push_back(2);
    p.push_back(3);
    p.push_back(4);
    p.push_back(5);
    p.push_back(6);
    cout << (*(p.begin())) << endl;
    cout << (*(p.begin() + 3)) << endl;
}
```

The benefit of using iterators in place of raw pointers is that the access is bounds-checked in debug builds (in VC++ at least), and it will seamlessly work with other types of sequential containers.